# Control two span tags using one function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, show-hide

I have two span tags and two p tags such as:

```
<span class="span1" ng-click="show()">Span_1</span>
<p class="p1" ng-show="var1">P_1</p>
<span class="span2" ng-click="show()">Span_2</span>
<p class="p2" ng-show="var1">P_2</p>
```

I am using AngularJS for this so what I want to achieve is to make a single function such as show() shown above to toggle the both the p tags how can i achieve that? Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.var1 = false;
    $scope.show = function() {
        $scope.var1 = $scope.var1 === false ? true: false;
    };
});
```

Upon clicking on Span_1 only p tag corresponding to it should show same as for Span_2 and I should achieve that only by one function.

Here is the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fzgpV68Q7UnHGHmHffZZ?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass variables from html. You can also add cases to make like ng-class or etc and on.

//Angular code(js)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.variableList = [{state:true},{state:false}];
    $scope.show = function(what,where) {
        switch(what){
          case 'display':
            return $scope.variableList[where].state;
            break;
          case 'click':
            $scope.variableList[where].state = !$scope.variableList[where].state;
            break;
          case 'class':
            return ($scope.variableList[where].state ? 'active' : '');
            break;
        }
    };
});
```

Usage(HTML):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in variableList">
    <span ng-class="show('class',$index);" ng-click="show('click',$index)">Span_{{$index+1}}</span>
    <p ng-class="show('class',$index);" ng-show="show('display',$index)">P_{{$index+1}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: updated code for dynamic tags added the updated code above and [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/k6aR12?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass span number as a parameter to function and than based on parameter change `$scope.var1` or `$scope.var2`. Function will look like?:

```
function show(varParam) { 
    if (varParam === 1) {
        $scope.var1 = !$scope.var1; //flip value    
    } else {
        $scope.var2 = !$scope.var2;
    }
}
```

Then in template you pas param during the function call like this:

```
ng-click="show(1)"
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/2y38zxja73Z1WDtQUsMw?p=preview)

Comment: If I have more than two span tags what should I do ?

Comment: You can create object storing your `ng-show` flags like `$scope.vars = {}` then in template `ng-show="vars[1]"`, `ng-show="vars[2]"` ... then in function instead of doing if .. else you can do `$scope.vars[varParam] = !!`$scope.vars[varParam]`

Answer (score 1):

You can also  write toggle method which toggle the visibility of span.
Ex -

```
<html ng-app='myApp' >
  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
<span class="span1" ng-click="toggle()">Span_1</span>
<p class="p1" ng-show="var">P_1</p>
<span class="span2" ng-click="toggle()">Span_2</span>
<p class="p2" ng-show="!var">P_2</p>
    </body>
  </html>
```

JS -

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.var = true;
    $scope.toggle = function() {
        $scope.var = !$scope.var;
    };
});
```